# Using try inside for loop to retrieve object without exception

Tags: python, django, exception, django-forms

I'm doing some form validation with Django for users adding a music album and its tracks to a database. Two albums of same name can exist as long as they're tied to diff. artists. This way, both artist name Beatles and Beatles Cover Band can both have an album called Hard Days Night in the db.

I've retrieved album objects with the same name called into a list called `retrieve_albums` and check each object for its artist using a for loop. The problem is that when I use `.get` on the queryset, I get error `DoesNotExist: <object> matching query does not exist`, which I say is a sort of descendant error of NameError. So I try putting inside a `try` block as shown.

```
>>> check_duplicate = False
>>> for album in retrieve_albums:
...     try:
...         if album.artists.get(name='Major Lazer'):
...             check_duplicate = True
...             break
...     except NameError:
...         pass
```

By the way, since these are ManyToManyKeys, I can't just call `album.artists(name=artist)`.

Ideally, the logic I'd like to do without `try` and `except` is:

```
for album in retrieve_albums:
    if album.artists.get(name='Major Lazer'):
        check_duplicate = True
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Using `get` throws a DoesNotExist error even just evaluating the if statement - it doesn't even get to the block. I also tried using `album.artists.get(name='Major Lazer', None)` but get `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT:

models.py for ref.

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    short_bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
    track_no = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Post your models.py file please. Edit: Please also include the QuerySet that populates ```retrieve_albums```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `get()` use `filter()` and `exists()`:

```
if album.artists.filter(name='Major Lazer').exists():
    check_duplicate = True 
    break
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Was using `filter` without `exists` and kept getting True with empty lists. Totally forgot about exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`album.artists` is a Django `QuerySet` object, not a Python `dict`. You need to catch the `DoesNotExist` exception instead. You can import it into your current namespace with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

See the [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get).

Comment: Thanks for this. Had no idea I had to explicitly import Django exceptions.